# What type is this lambda's parameter?

Tags: c++, lambda, auto

I was experimenting with functional programming, and I wrote this.

```
[=](auto p) { 
    return [=](auto q) { 
        return p(q)(p); 
    }; 
})
```

I started wondering how this is possible, what is the type of p?

So, I wrote something like this.

```
template<class Type>
using LambdaType = std::function<std::function<Type(Type)>(Type)>;
```

and

```
[=](LambdaType<int> p) {
    return [=](LambdaType<int> q) {
        return p(q)(p);
    };
}
```

When compiling it, the compiler would give me errors.

```
error C2664: 'std::function<Type (int)> std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::operator ()(int) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::function<std::function<Type (int)> (int)>' to 'int'
error C2664: 'main::<lambda_cec7eb77d9cd29f3c40710200090f154>::()::<lambda_b8db28542cb51159223ad8d89c63d794>::()::<lambda_224126017af42fcee190e88f299089fc>::()::<lambda_415db9fd88f1008b25af42ccb33b1c77> main::<lambda_cec7eb77d9cd29f3c40710200090f154>::()::<lambda_b8db28542cb51159223ad8d89c63d794>::()::<lambda_224126017af42fcee190e88f299089fc>::operator ()(std::function<std::function<Type (std::function<std::function<int (int)> (int)>)> (std::function<std::function<int (int)> (int)>)>) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'main::<lambda_cec7eb77d9cd29f3c40710200090f154>::()::<lambda_b8db28542cb51159223ad8d89c63d794>::()::<lambda_fa72c454c823301ba6dfa9cba6f558e0>' to 'std::function<std::function<Type (std::function<std::function<int (int)> (int)>)> (std::function<std::function<int (int)> (int)>)>'
```

But that's when I realized that p only takes in ints, but p needs to be a `LambdaType<LambdaType<int>>` to take in q
but when you change p to a `LambdaType<LambdaType<int>>`, then p only takes in `LambdaType<int>` but p is not a `LambdaType<int>`, and it needs to be a `LambdaType<LambdaType<LambdaType<int>>>` to take in p.

So, what type is p?

Oh by the way, this is my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: The type of 'p' is not known until the lambda is used in a context where it gets evaluated. This is really just a different way of writing a template function. `template <typename type_of_p> auto lambda(type_of_p p)...` what is `type_of_p` -- you don't know until you actually use it.

Comment: if you actually calls that lambda, it would be easier for you to see what happened.

Comment: The type is deduced at compile time and it depends on what type you use it with.

Comment: Your confusion seems to be caused because of the fact that a lambda is not of type `std::function<SOME_SIGNATURE>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we're looking for four types `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S` such as:

- `P(Q) -> R`
- `R(P) -> S`

`Q` and `S` are no more than placeholder argument and return types, so we don't need anything from them:

```
struct Q { };
struct S { };
```

`P` and `R` are more interesting, because there's a loop in the specification of the signatures they need: `R` is both the result of an invocation of `P`, and able to be called with another `P`. That makes it impossible to declare with a function type or a lambda type, which are only defined by their (here infinitely recursive) signature.

But C++ can sort it out easily with functors -- just give the thing a name, and with the help of a simple forward-declaration you can create your loopy functor just fine:

```
struct P;

struct R {
    S operator()(P) const;
};

struct P {
    R operator()(Q) const { return {}; }
};

inline S R::operator()(P) const { return {}; }
```

[Live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c0e5c4f23ce5528)

---

Lastly, C++ has templates, and that gives us the power to solve this with the most boring solution ever:

```
struct O {
    template <class T>
    O const &operator()(T) const { return *this; }
};
```

Such an `O` will just swallow whatever you call it with, even an instance of itself, and not even care.

[Live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/352e71ed3b25ad35)

Answer (score 1):

### Implementation level

In `c++`, Lambda is implemented with a `struct` with `operator()`, whose name is unknown. Because the keyword `auto` here means type is generic, so `template` is required. You must explicitly instantiate the struct by giving the arguments for the struct templates, then what `'a` and `'b` stand for can be determined.

### Abstract level

```
p(q)(p);
  ↑
```

Assume the type of `p` is `'a->'b`

- `'a` is the type of parameter
- `'b` is the return type

---

```
p(q)(p);
     ↑
```

We can see the return type(`'b`) can receive a `p`, whose type is `'a->'b`, so we can replace `'b` with `'a->'b`. Is the the problem resolved? No!

Unlike trival recursive function like `factorial`:

```
std::function<int(int)> factorial = [&](int a) {return a == 1 ? 1 : a*factorial(a-1);};
```

- For `Factorial`: its return type still is not relying on the type(`Factorial`) itself.
- For `p`: its return type relies on `p`s type. So the type is infinite.

Just like @molbdnilo's comment:

> It has an infinite type and can't be instantiated.

Comment: If `p` is `a -> a -> b`, then `p(q)` would be `a -> b`, but it must be `a -> a -> b -> c` for some `c`.

Comment: @molbdnilo the type of 'b' can also be 'b->c'.

Comment: Oops, I meant `(a -> a -> b) -> c`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, you are right. It may be better to say that we can never deduce the type of  `'a` because there is no need to introduce a third type `c` or `d`. I'll update my answer later : )

Comment: The problem is that the type is infinite. If `p` has the type `P`, `p(q)` has the type `P -> c` for some `c`, so `P` must be `a -> P -> c`for some `a` and `c`. Which is impossible.